# confused about time complexity for two approaches of leetcode problem -Subset II

Tags: python, recursion, time-complexity, subset, backtracking

I have learned two approaches for solving the following problem:

> Given an integer array nums that may contain duplicates, return all possible
> subsets (the power set).
>
> The solution set must not contain duplicate subsets. Return the solution in any order.

I'm unable to identify the time complexity of these two approaches.
According to me it will be O(2^n*n) for both the approches. But in internet it is given that the time complexity for first one is...

> O(2^n*(k log(x))). 2^n for generating every subset and k*log(x) to insert every combination of average length k

1st approach :

```
 def subsetsWithDup(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """
        def fun(i,l,result):
            #print(l)
            if(i==len(nums)):
                if(l not in result):
                    result.append(l[:])
                return
            l.append(nums[i])
            fun(i+1,l,result)
            l.pop()
            fun(i+1,l,result)    
            return result
        nums.sort()    
        return fun(0,[],[])
```

2nd approach :

```
class Solution:
    def subsetsWithDup(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        ans = []
        ds = []


        def findSubsets(ind: int):
            ans.append(ds[:])
            for i in range(ind, len(nums)):
                if i != ind and nums[i] == nums[i - 1]:
                    continue
                ds.append(nums[i])
                findSubsets(i + 1)
                ds.pop()
        nums.sort()
        findSubsets(0)
        return ans
```

Comment: It is unclear what k and x mean.